# Inserting Data into Related Oracle Tables and Maintain List of Identity values

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert, oracle12c, sql-returning

I have a data staging table that is populated by procedural code.

```
TABLE BatchRecord{
    BatchRecordID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    BatchID NUMBER, --Assigned by the procedural code
    RecordID NUMBER, --Relative to the batch
    FieldID NUMBER, --Assigned by the procedural code; FK to another table
    Value VARCHAR2(MAX)
    Instance NUMBER}
```

Each BatchRecord then needs to be transformed into three related tables: Records, RecordFields, FieldValues.

```
TABLE Record{
    RecordID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    BatchID NUMBER, --Same from BatchRecords}

TABLE RecordFields{
    RecordFieldID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    RecordID NUMBER, --FK from Records
    FieldID NUNBER --Same from BatchRecords}

TABLE FieldValues{
    RecordFieldID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    Instance NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, --Same from BatchRecords
    Value VARCHAR2(MAX) --Same from BatchRecords}
```

In SQL Server, I can accomplish this using a `MERGE` statement and using `OUTPUT` to capture the newly inserted keys:

```
CREATE TABLE #InsertedRecords(RecordID INT, NewRecordID INT);

MERGE INTO Records USING (
    SELECT RecordID
    FROM BatchRecords
    WHERE BatchID = @BatchID
    GROUP BY RecordID) AS BR ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (BatchID)
    VALUES (@BatchID)
    OUTPUT BR.RecordID, INSERTED.RecordID INTO #InsertedRecords;
```

A similar approach is taken to insert RecordFields, and an `INSERT...SELECT` statement is used to insert into FieldValues.

However, in Oracle, it is not possible to use `RETURNING` (the equivalent to `OUTPUT`) in a `MERGE` statement, or even in a `SELECT...INTO` statement.

Is there a possible way to accomplish the same task in Oracle while also avoiding a `FORALL` loop as the total number of BatchRecords could be upward of several million?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using oracle PIPELINE function to select all records from BatchRecord and then pipe row into different tables. If needed I could show an example.

**EDIT**

```
create or replace package test_pkg AS

  TYPE REP_CURS IS REF CURSOR;
  TYPE output_REC IS RECORD(
    RecordID_    number,
    BatchID_  number);

  TYPE output_TAB IS TABLE OF output_REC;

  FUNCTION Get_Data RETURN output_TAB
    PIPELINED;

END test_pkg;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg IS

  FUNCTION Get_Data RETURN output_TAB
    PIPELINED IS

    output_REC_ output_REC;
    rep_lines_  REP_CURS;
    stmt_       VARCHAR2(5000);
    table_rec_  BatchRecord%ROWTYPE;

  begin
    stmt_ := '  (select BatchRecordID,BatchID ....Instance  from BatchRecord)  ';

    OPEN rep_lines_ FOR stmt_;
    LOOP
      FETCH rep_lines_
        INTO table_rec_;
      EXIT WHEN rep_lines_%NOTFOUND;

      output_REC_.RecordID_   := <<whatever valu that you want>;
      output_REC_.BatchID_ := table_rec_.BatchID;


        PIPE ROW(output_REC_);

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE rep_lines_;

    RETURN;
  exception
    when others then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error:' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE ||
                           DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK ||
                           DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK);
  END Get_Data;

END test_pkg;
```

I have shown an example for inserting into Record. You have to do similarly for the other two tables as well. Hope this helps !!

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: I have edited the solution to include the example. Take a look.

Comment: This method still requires you to loop through all row in BatchRecords.  Since this table can be millions of rows, is there any method to avoid looping?